# Pull bitbucket repository in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, bitbucket, ssh-keys, openssh

for some reasons I have a python project with specific requirements that pull private repositories from bitbucket

*requirements.txt*

```
git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/mycompany/myproject.git
```

I can install everything in my local env, no problems. So to forward my ssh config to the Dockerfile, I use the ssh option of docker compose.

*docker-compose.yml*

```
services:
  myservice:
    ...
    build:
      context: .
      ssh:
        - default
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
```

*Dockerfile*

```
#install git, openssh, libpq
...
#ssh config
RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh
RUN touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN curl https://bitbucket.org/site/ssh >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

#install dependencies
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
COPY ./myproject /var/www/html/myproject
WORKDIR /var/www/html/myproject
RUN pip3 install -r /var/www/html/myproject/requirements.txt
```

for some reasons, when I try to build it, the last line exits with error:

```
 git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey)
```

Is this related to the recent key switches from bitbucket ? I wonder what am I doing wrong. When I open the .ssh/known_hosts in my container, the bitbucket keys are in place.

**UPDATE**:

It seems I can install the requirements of my project if I try to install it directly from the bash of my container

```
docker compose run flask /bin/bash
```

which connect me to my container bash as root and then:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

yet, I'd like to not have to do this for every build.

Comment: The known hosts is to make sure no one is tampering with things so you basically check if a given host is still the same you logged into last time (very broadly speaking). `ssh` in the compose file is trying to mount in the agent socket. Where are you running this? Is that **inside** a bitbucket pipeline?

Comment: @RickRackow no, I'm just trying to build this container on my local machine